# Which is the stable version of Spring boot in maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, maven

The latest version of spring boot is 2.7.5 from the Maven Repo is released .

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter

Is spring boot 2.7.5 version stable version ? Can we use the sprint 2.7.5 version in projects .On what basis we can consider that this version is released and we can go ahead and start using the projects .Could anyone suggest on this please .

Comment: Since 20th Oct. 2022, 2.7.5 is latest `RELEASE` version. When there is no `SNAPSHOT`, `M` (mile stone) or `RC` (release candidate) in the "version string", you can assume you have a "release"(d) version...

Comment: (all) Spring blog (category: releases): https://spring.io/blog/category/releases, spring-boot, github Release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes

Comment: The most recent version can be identified by: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent Also via the supported version (which is very important): https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the latest stable version on Spring boot. You can see that it's widely used in the Usege section
[image: Maven Artifactory]

Answer (score 1):

As the time of writing: Yes, 2.7.5 is the latest *release* version of Spring Boot.

However, it should be noted that Spring Boot 3.0.0 should also be coming out this year.The current latest version there (as of the time of writing is 3.0.0-RC2 as [seen in the release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes).
This version is a Release Candidate so while it should be almost ready, there might still be a few (breaking) changes and fixes.

If you are starting a new project (especially if it won't release that soon), you *might* want to use Spring Boot 3 (RC2) now and switch to the proper release version once it comes out.
This way, you can use Spring 6/Spring Boot 3 without having the migration work.

If you want to use Release Candidates, you would need to add the milestone repository to your build configuration (e.g. pom.xml):

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0.0 will be released on 24.November (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestones)...Very important Spring Boot 3.0.0 requires JDK17+

Comment: And it uses Jakarta EE and there are a few breaking changes. This is why it might be worth to consider for new projects although it isn't _yet_ released as one doesn't have to do all the migration work.